# Pass custom Checkout field value to Stripe gateway in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have added a custom checkout field to my WooCommerce web site. I have added and enabled [Stripe](https://woocommerce.com/products/stripe/) plugin, as payment gateway… Is there a way to have this custom fields value sent as data to Stripe payment gateway?

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find anything.

Comment: This is probably best answered by looking through the woocommerce Stripe plugin, if you can do that yourself, for the point where it assembles the data sent to Stripe to see if there are any obvious hooks you can use. If not, you can always fork the plugin and add the extra function to your own private copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`wc_stripe_payment_metadata`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/#filter-hooks) dedicated filter hook to add (pass) some custom meta data to Stripe gateway, this way:

```
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_payment_metadata', 'stripe_payment_metadata_filter_callback', 10, 3 );
function stripe_payment_metadata_filter_callback( $metadata, $order, $prepared_source ) {
    // Here below define your custom field meta key (as it's saved in wp_postmeta DB table)
    $metadata = 'custom_meta_key';

    $metadata[ __( 'Custom Label Text (or meta key)', 'woocommerce-gateway-stripe' ) ] = $order->get_meta($meta_key);

    return $metadata;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

---

Related threads:

- [WooCommerce Stripe official documentation - Filter Hooks section](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/#filter-hooks)
- [WooCommerce Stripe: Add Custom MetaData *(April 2018)*](https://remicorson.com/woocommerce-stripe-add-custom-metadata/)
- [Send Variation options to stripe as metadata with WooCommerce *(May 2018)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294745/send-variation-options-to-stripe-as-metadata-with-woocommerce)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had already found the answer on searching stripe code but was busy with its implementation. Thank you